# There are uniformly distributed sequences, but do similar sequences exist for other distributions? If they exist, what are they called?

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-distributions

A [uniformly distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence) sequence $(a_n)\subset[0,1]$ has a property that

\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}\cap[0,x]|}{n} = x,
\end{equation}
for $x\in[0,1]$. I am looking for a sequence such that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}\cap[0,x]|}{n} = F(x),
\end{equation}
for some more general function $F(x)$. Do such sequences exist and if they do, what are they called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $(a_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is equidistributed and $F:[0,1]\longrightarrow [0,1]$ is continuous and striclty non-decreasing, then $F^{-1}(a_i)\in [0,x]$ if and only if $a_i\in [F(0),F(x)]$ so that
$$ \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{|\{F^{-1}(a_1),\ldots,F^{-1}(a_n)\}\cap [0,x]|}{n}=F(x)-F(0). $$
If you suppose $F(0)=0$ (which is not a strong assumption if you want $F$ to satisfy such an equality) then all these functions answer your question. To my knowledge, such sequences have no particular name.